# How to prevent SQL query params/values from appearing in Google Cloud PostgreSQL logs?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, postgresql-11

I have added logging for all DDL and DML queries on my Google Cloud PostgreSQL database instance.

The queries are logged, but I want to avoid query params or column values from appearing in the logs. 
Is there a way to prevent this sensitive data from logging?

Currently, the entire query is logged as a single string with commands and values.

I tried to find if there's a setting which can be enabled using Database Flag on Google Cloud as I can't access `postgresql.conf` file using Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: Have you tried using [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129924/how-to-disable-the-logging-of-parameter-values-in-postgresql) ? Something like:

\set VAR VALUE;
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = :VAR;

Comment: editing the Cloud SQL instance's flags with [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#postgres-l)

Comment: @asbovelw, I tried this answer. However, it did not work. The whole query is getting logged. If I write a DELETE query with id = value. The value shows in plain text, not as a substituted param.

Comment: i have been investigating, and it seems it is not possible to do this in Cloud SQL for Postgres. you can make a Feature Request so Google can work on this here: http://issuetracker.google.com/